# Left align Zurb Foundation menu in top bar mobile

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've tried a few tricks to try and move the menu on the left, but none of the regular classes appears to be fit to toggle this option, especially on mobile devices (which is what I'm designing for).

Is there a mobile device CSS fix for this? (note I've already got "class='left'" on the menu area).

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: false">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#"><img style="width: 150px;"src="yourmomslogo.png"></a></h1>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="active"><a href="pushthatthang.doit">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="alwaysthebestcats.meow">Your Cats</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let see the [**doc**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html#build-with-html-classes)
If you change **left** by **right** in this code

```
<ul class="left">
   <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see the link goes to the right, so the **left class** changes the position of the link (so the menu for you)

Comment: This does not change the position of the menu on mobile devices, which is what the OP asked for. Additionally, the OP has already done what this answer instructs him to do.

Comment: Earlier it wouldn't work. Now sometimes it works. But it doesn't work right. Here is an example where it is on the left but it is broken: http://jsfiddle.net/eoqnwgrL/2/